# Cannot get access to directory that I was just in 5 minutes ago

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm using a Linux/Debian.
In the following series of commands I was in directory `temp_dir4`.  I mounted a google storage bucket to that directory and then changed the permissions otherwise I would have gotten a permission denied error when I ran `ls`.

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks/temp_dir4$ sudo -i chmod o+rx -R /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks/temp_dir4$ sudo gcsfuse deduction1 /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
Using mount point: /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
File system has been successfully mounted.
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks/temp_dir4$ ls
```

Next I ran a program over at a different directory which was a python program that would just read the files in the directory.  This program was:

```
lst1 = os.listdir('/mnt/disks/temp_dir4/')
print (lst1)
```

I got the following error:

```
File "fix_mistakes.py", line 1733, in <module>
    temp17()
  File "fix_mistakes.py", line 1729, in temp17
    lst1 = os.listdir('/mnt/disks/temp_dir4/')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/mnt/disks/temp_dir4/'
```

I then tried to go back to that directory and change the permissions but I could not:

```
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ sudo -i chmod o+rx -R /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ cd temp_dir4
-bash: cd: temp_dir4: Permission denied

kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ sudo -i chmod a+w /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
kylefoley@kfoley76:/mnt/disks$ cd temp_dir4
-bash: cd: temp_dir4: Permission denied
```

Also, I need to change the permissions of temp_dir4 so that when I run that python program I won't get hit with another permission denied error.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with `gcsfuse` *at all* but I know few general facts:

1. Mounting anything over a directory will not affect programs that already use the directory. Your `ls` inherited its working directory from the shell, this is *not* the mounted filesystem. But if you did `ls "$PWD"` (equivalent to `ls /mnt/disks/temp_dir4`) or `cd "$PWD"`, then you would probably hit `Permission denied` because now `/mnt/disks/temp_dir4` refers to the mounted filesystem.
2. `gcsfuse` uses [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), Filesystem in Userspace. If you mount as `root` then it will work for `root`; unless you use `allow_other` (see [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.fuse.8.html)). It's normal `chown` and `chmod` don't work with FUSE. The [documentation of the tool](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) reads:

   > If you know what you are doing, you can override these behaviors with the `allow_other` mount option supported by fuse and with the `--uid` and `--gid` flags supported by gcsfuse. Be careful, this may have security implications!

   To know the security implications read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1242432/432690).

   An example command:

   ```
   sudo mount -t gcsfuse -o rw,allow_other,uid=1001,gid=1001 deduction1 /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
   ```

   Where `-t gcsfuse` tells `mount` to use `mount.gcsfuse`. Your original command with `gcsfuse` as the executable is just a handy alternative (although I'm not sure if it allows you to pass `allow_other`; it should).

   But to mount the filesystem for your current user only, it's enough (and safer!) to mount it as the current user (without `sudo`). One of the points of having a Filesystem in *Userspace* is to allow a regular user to mount it. The [already mentioned documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md) states:

   > Important: You should run `gcsfuse` as the user who will be using the file system, not as root. Similarly, the directory should be owned by that user. Do not use `sudo` for either of the steps above or you will wind up with permissions issues.

   So unmount the filesystem you mounted as `root` (if still mounted):

   ```
   sudo fusermount -u /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
   ```

   Then simply mount it as your user:

   ```
   gcsfuse deduction1 /mnt/disks/temp_dir4
   ```

   If this succeeds then your user will be able to use the filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I'm no longer having permission problems for unknown reasons.  But now python's `os.listdir(path)` cannot read the contents of the directory. You seem like you know something about gcsfuse so maybe you can help.  I have a thread started over here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59947320/not-able-to-read-files-on-gcsfuse-mounted-disk